# Noise Estimation in Real space and equivalence in Fourier space

Tags: image-processing, fft, noise

Say I have an image *X* in **reciprocal space**. 
I have perturbed *X* in **recirpocal space** with Gaussian noise (*μ=0, σ=σ*); both the real part and the complex part of the DFT have been perturbed.

I estimated the noise variance of the perturbed image in **real space** using a noise estimator based on the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix determined from patches of the perturbed image.

I am trying to find the correspondance/mapping of the **real space** noise variance with the **reciprocal space** noise variance. 
Since both noise models are Gaussian with *μ=0*, I am expecting a 1-1 mapping between the two variances. 
My first idea was to compute the inverse Fourier transform of a Gaussian as a first approximation of the two noise variance. Thus, giving

σ<sub>real space</sub> *∝* 1/σ<sub>reciprocal space</sub>

However, this does not give the correct answer. 
Obviously, I understand that adding noise in Fourier space perturbed the whole image for every frequency perturbed (each frequency contributes to the whole image). 
As a test, I created a set of images with different noise variance in reciprocal space and estimated the real space noise variance.

Here is the result of the experiment:
[image]

As expected, it does not seem there is an easy mapping between the two noise variances.
Thus, I was wondering if such correspondance between the noise variances exists.
 
If you could point me toward the correct direction or have any insight on the matter, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If the added noise samples are independent and identically distributed, and independent of the original image, then you could use Parseval's theorem to show a linear proportionality between the two variances. Given that it isn't the case, either the independence assumptions are not valid (how are you generating the noise?), or you are observing the result of noise estimation errors.

Comment: Thank you @SleuthEye for the reply. I do not see why independence assumptions would not hold here. I apply independent noise to each  real and complex components that follow a given gaussian distribution.

For the noise estimation error, I rely on a publish algorithm to estimate the noise, which shows good accuracy (according to the paper results at least).

Comment: the surprising statement is this: " it does not seem there is an easy mapping between the two noise variances": what do you expect a straight line? a perfect circle? this is an easy curve